# How to trim Devanagri text from a given string by the help of unicodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I want to write a python code that can fetch out Devanagari text from the given string, but I don't know how to use Unicode for the same.
My input will be in this form

```
Translate 'अंक'  
36  अ       [V]  
36  ं       [n]  
57  ं  (क [N]  
36  क [kV]  
---  
(hi)'VNk(en)
```

I want text written in Devanagari only not that numbers or English alphabets.
My output should be in this form
अंक  अ  ं  ं(क  क

I Have tried this code

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open("C:/Users/prince/Desktop/hindi.txt",mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8")
file_dic = codecs.open("C:/Users/prince/Desktop/dic.txt",mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8")
for i in range (0, 330):
    u = file.read()
    if (u[i] >= 0900) && (u[i]<= 097F):
        file_dic.write(u)
        file_dic.write('  ')
```

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example, perhaps some sample code that you've tried?

Comment: I did not get any information on how to use Unicode value of text in python. I have included code in question. @Daenyth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression will keep your Devanagari text together.  Your example would print spaces between every character.  Below also adds the Devanagari Extended range in Unicode as well:

```
#!python3
#coding:utf8

import re

text = '''\
Translate 'अंक'  
36  अ       [V]  
36  ं       [n]  
57  ं  (क [N]  
36  क [kV]
---  
(hi)'VNk(en)
'''

print(' '.join(re.findall(r'[\u0900-\u097f\ua8e0-\ua8ff]+',text)))
```

Output:

```
अंक अ ं ं क क
```

Writing to the files in your example:

```
import re

with open("C:/Users/prince/Desktop/hindi.txt",mode = "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()
with open("C:/Users/prince/Desktop/dic.txt",mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file_dic:
    file_dic.write(' '.join(re.findall(r'[\u0900-\u097f\ua8e0-\ua8ff]+',text)))
```

Comment: Sir can you please explain   `{ print(' '.join(re.findall(r'[\u0900-\u097f\ua8e0-\ua8ff]+',text))) }` this piece of code. And sir I also want to include some symbols in my output like [ '(' ,  ')' , '_' and 'B' ]. How can I include them in output
@MarkTolonen

Comment: [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a module that implements [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  `[\u0900-\u097f\ua8e0-\ua8ff]+` matches one or more Unicode characters in the ranges 900h-97fh and a8e0h-a8ffh.  [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of the matching strings, and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) merges the list of strings into a single string separated by spaces.

Comment: Thank you sir. Sir what about including those extra symbols and alphabets in output?  I am making a dictionary for speech recognition so I need those extra symbols in my dictionary. So please help me out with that thing also.

Comment: @Prince your question does not include how you want the extra symbols in your output.  Ask a new question with a new example.

Comment: To trim extra symbols also with Devanagari text just add them to the range class and the new range class will be  `[\u0900-\u097f\ua8e0-\ua8ff()_B]`